# Average calcul on js loop

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

i'm trying to do a loop to add an average line on my d3js chart but i have a problem. I have this return that i try to adapt to return my average:

```
var param = copy.map(function(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(d => {
                return {date: d.date, degrees: +d[id]}})
        };
    });
```

And i don't know how to modify it to give me the average at the "degree" attribute. The +d increment the degree value with the id filter.

i already made this but it's only working when I have two charts on my graphic, i need to adapt the number of (+d[copy[n])) but I don't know how to do it

```
var paramAvg = copy.map(function() {
        return {
            id: "Moyenne",
            values: data.map(d => {
                return {date: d.date, degrees: ((+d[copy[0]]) + (+d[copy[1]]) ) /copy.length}})
        };
    });
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What is in your data array? Can you not use a reducer which sums all the values and then divides by the length of the data array when the index is equal to data.length - 1?

```

Comment: copy.map(function(data),where define data variable ,again what is the value of copy array object